# ng-repeat with jquery and rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, href, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im using ng-repeat to iterate over some json objects and trying to add {{code.id}} as a parameter for a rails route e.g.

```
card_url( @car, {{card.id}} )
```

I know this is not possible due to the rails rendering the route way before the JavaScript fires in. Does Anyone have any suggestions to get around this. I was thinking maybe I could use jquery to change the href once everything has loaded but how would I use ng-repeat object in Jquery?.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an HTML `anchor` tag with the right `href` rather than using rails url helper

Something like

```
<a href="/cards/{{ card.id }}"> my link </a>
```

Comment: Why not? Event if you write ruby code, the output is HTML.

Comment: Just incase routes change don't want to break links on site.

Comment: Even to use jquery to modify the href, you will have to hardcode it in your javascript code